# display pages in php login script

Tags: php, html, security, authentication, login-script

Please forgive my lack of experience with the subject everyone.

I have created a basic php login system and am trying to give people secure access to certain pages.

My problem is I can only add the logged in page you see below.

```
if ($login->isUserLoggedIn() == true) {
    include("views/logged_in.php");
```

How do I add more pages to secure view. assuming i have already linked them to the logged_in file. When I upload them to the server i keep getting 403. Paths are all correct.

```
<?php


if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.3.7', '<')) {
    exit("Sorry, Simple PHP Login does not run on a PHP version smaller than 5.3.7 !");
} else if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.5.0', '<')) {

  require_once("libraries/password_compatibility_library.php");
}


require_once("config/db.php");


require_once("classes/Login.php");


$login = new Login();


if ($login->isUserLoggedIn() == true) {


    include("views/logged_in.php");


} else {

    include("views/not_logged_in.php");
}
```

Comment: That is not adding a page within the security umbrella. You are simply including a file if the user is logged in.

Comment: ok how would i add the file to this script ? sorry Im not too well with php

Comment: please provide your main script  !

Comment: <?php


if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.3.7', '<')) {
    exit("Sorry, Simple PHP Login does not run on a PHP version smaller than 5.3.7 !");
} else if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.5.0', '<')) {
    
  require_once("libraries/password_compatibility_library.php");
}


require_once("config/db.php");


require_once("classes/Login.php");


$login = new Login();


if ($login->isUserLoggedIn() == true) {
    
 
    include("views/logged_in.php");
 

} else {
    
    include("views/not_logged_in.php");
}

Answer (score 0):

you may have apply control session with the superglobar $_session. Please check this $_SESSION si like $_GET or $_POST variable.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php

Answer (score 0):

The problem with what you show is that is does not seem you are defining a page as requiring a login anywhere.

You would probably like to have something like this near the top of each page (maybe in a global include) that would execute before any other headers are sent:

```
if (page_requires_login() && $login->isUserLoggedIn() == false) {
    // send 403 header and exit or redirect or whatever it is you want to do with insecure requests
}

// continue page logic
```

Of course here the problem is what to do for determining if the page requires a login (represented in my example by a function call `page_requires_login` to make this determination)

There are any number of ways to achieve this. You could hard code an array of pages that require login and have a function to check if the currently executing page is in this array.  You could pull a list of secure pages from the database for comparison, etc. Without understanding your app, we can;t really give you much advice on what may be best for you in this regard.